# How can I delete the SharePoint site for a private channel in Microsoft Teams?

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-collection, delete

As you can see on the screenshot below, I can't delete my site. This command is missing under the menu item Website information. Also in the advanced settings I can't find any delete functionality.

[image: Edit website information]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Privat channels always have their own SharePoint site. This is by design for security reasons. There is no way around it. Standard (not private) channels use the SP site of the team.

Answer (score 3):

Each team in Microsoft Teams has a team site in SharePoint Online, and each standard channel in a team gets a folder within the default team site document library. Files shared within a conversation are automatically added to the document library, and permissions and file security options set in SharePoint are automatically reflected within Teams.

You can refer to the following articles to learn more about the relationship between the Microsoft team and SharePoint Online:

[How SharePoint Online and OneDrive for Business interact with Microsoft Teams](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/sharepoint-onedrive-interact)

As Susan mentioned, if you delete this site or this library, the shared files and history of all users in this channel will be deleted, and it is not recommended that you delete this site.

Comment: If you create a private channel a separate site is created.

Comment: @NaimMurati Thank you very much for your comment! I created a private channel, so a new site was created...Do you know if its possible to create a private channel without creating a completely new page?

Comment: No, see my answer.

Comment: It's impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Despite not knowing any german, this is a screen shot of deleting a site and not a page.
Secondly the 'Delete site' is beneath the sentence "alle websitee...". I cannot comment if it is there or not since the screenshot stops exactly before.
Third the 'delete site' link is also available in Site Settings (which is your 'alle websitee...') under "site actions".

If you cannot get to Site Settings and see this command it means you are not site owner or the site owner permission level assigned to you as been modified.

Comment: There is no option "delete" or something else... I have the full permissions. This site was created when I created a new channel in my team. This team has his own teamsite, I created a new Channel and this site was created... If you know what I mean.

Comment: When 1 Microsoft Team is created, a sharepoint website is created with a default document library with 1 folder that corresponds to the 1st default channel (which is normally called 'general'). When a second channel is created in the same Microsoft Team instance, a SECOND folder is created in the same document library that will correspond to the second channel. Creating a second channel does NOT create a new website. 1 Microsoft Team = Multiple channels = 1 SharePoint site. If you delete the site, most likely you will delete the whole Microsoft team as well

Comment: I has created a private channel... so this will create a new sharepoint page. Do you know if its possible to create a private channel without creating a completely new page?